# ExtJS using store for line chart where the keys aren't known

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to use a line chart to display browser usage over time, however, when defining the model, I don't want to hard code the names of the browsers as the fields.

So, I don't want to do something like this:

```
Ext.define('BrowserCount', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'Year',
            type: "int"
        }, {
            name: "Firefox",
            type: "int"
        }, {
            name: "MSIE",
            type: "int"
        }, {
            name: "Chrome",
            type: "int"
        }]
    });

    var browserCountStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'AggregatedBrowserUsage',
        data: [{
            Year: '2011',
            Firefox: 4952,
            MSIE: 4613,
            Chrome: 1401
        }, {
            Year: '2012',
            Firefox: 952,
            MSIE: 613,
            Chrome: 401
        }]
    });
```

Instead I want to define my models as follows:

```
Ext.define('Browser', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'Browser',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'Alias',
            type: 'string'
        }],
        hasMany: {
            model: 'AggregatedTotal',
            name: 'aggregatedtotal',
            associationkey: 'AggregatedTotals'
        }
    });

    Ext.define('AggregatedTotal', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'Year',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'Count',
            type: 'int'
        }],
        belongsTo: 'Browser'
    });

    var browsers = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Browser',
        data: [{
            Browser: 'Firefox',
            Alias: 'Firefox',
            AggregatedTotals: [{
                Year: 2011,
                Count: 4952
            }, {
                Year: 2012,
                Count: 999
            }]
        }, {
            Browser: 'Chrome',
            Alias: 'Chrome',
            AggregatedTotals: [{
                Year: 2011,
                Count: 3552
            }, {
                Year: 2012,
                Count: 6000
            }]
        }, {
            Browser: 'MSIE',
            Alias: 'Internet Explorer',
            AggregatedTotals: [{
                Year: 2011,
                Count: 100
            }, {
                Year: 2012,
                Count: 50
            }]
        }]
    });
```

If defined in the latter fashion, how can I set up the store and fields config options of the chart such that it displays the same information as if the stores were defined in the same manner as the first example? Futhermore, when an item in the line chart is visited/hovered over, I want to access the fields of the Browser model like Browser and Alias (see example).

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/habsfan/hSmcL/1/) to the example.